# ActiveMQ How to delete only some scheduled elements

Tags: jms, activemq-classic, scheduler

I have an ActiveMQ messaging system and i want to delete only some scheduled messages from the queue.

I can delete all the scheduled message via a `ScheduledMessage.AMQ_SCHEDULER_ACTION_REMOVEALL` 
message sent to the queue.

I can delete a message by ID by sending a `AMQ_SCHEDULER_ACTION_REMOVE` message.

But is there a way to delete all messages with a selector (maybe a property on the message) ?

I checked the Jolokia REST API of ActiveMQ, but it seems that informations on Scheduled messages are not available.

Answer (score 2):

No that functionality is not currently supported.  You would need to take a look at the source code and implement this yourself and then contribute it back to the community.  There is a fine line though were trying to use a message broker as a database will turn around and bite you so I'd recommend caution on that front.

You'd need to implement a new remove directive like AMQ_SCHEDULER_ACTION_REMOVE_SELECTED and define how the selector works in that case, SQL92 string etc and then add an API on the Scheduler store interface and implement it in the Scheduler implementation in the KahaDB module.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Tim.